# How to make the discord bot add the user id to the code?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I wanted a bot I wanted the bot when the user wrote the command /add_admin (here is the user id ) And the bot added it either to a separate file or to the code admin = [user id] and I don't know how to do it, I write the code in Replit python

I haven't tried anything because I don't know how

Comment: Try reading through this tutorial to [add a bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/discord.html#discord-intro) and then this [discord.py example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store it in a `.json` file.

Say you created an `admins.json` in a separate `/admins` folder, this is how I would set it up:

```py
async def add_admin(ctx, id):
        # If you want there to be only one admin
        dict = {"Admin": id}
        with open('./admins/admins.json', "r+") as f:
            json.dump(dict, f)
        await ctx.send(f"Noted {id} as admin.")
```

This is just a simple example of writing into JSON through python. In this instance, the key **"Admin"** in this dictionary will be updated to any value whenever the command is re-run. If you wanted there to be more than one admin in the JSON, then you'd use something like `.update()`.

Comment: @Jonoto You need to `import json`

Comment: Consider an actual database instead of a JSON file. There's a lot of reasons, but JSON won't even work because you're on replit, which has an ephemeral file system so they get wiped all the time @Jonoto.